# Would dipole antenna work in the following case?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

So a dipole antenna is supposed to work with AC supplies.

But would it still produce propagating EM waves if pulses of DC are supplied instead of AC current?
show in the image:
[image]

Comment: "Pulses" of dc is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean a periodic voltage pulse sequence, say $$s(t)=A \text{ when } 0<t<dT_p, \\p(t+T_p)=p(t) \\\text {  and } p(t)= 0\text{ otherwise}$$ and $0<d<1$. This can be expanded in a Fourier series, and each term in it is a sinusoid that can applied to the the antenna and transmitted. If the antenna is properly tuned (matched, the radiation impedance is real) to the fundamental $1/T_p$ or to any of the harmonic frequencies $m/T_p;m\ge2$ then it is not going to work properly for two reasons

(1) because for the *other* frequencies they will all have their own and different radiation pattern,

(2) because the matching will not be uniform, and the amplitudes at which the individual terms are transmitted will not be the one that add to the pulse sequence.

Comment: Also maybe this will be obvious but the DC component of the waveform will not be transmitted at all, so on the receiving end, whatever signal you get would have zero time average (i.e. AC coupled, or shifted "downward").

Comment: @Puk that is not quite right. The dc component of the voltage will set set up an electrostatic field of a static dipole whose intensity is proportional to the voltage amplitude. So to the extent it is meaningful to say that one can "transmit" dc, yes, this will do it.

Comment: Yes, you might measure a small DC offset, but this is not a signal transmitted in the usual sense we speak of antennas transmitting signals via radiation. In particular, the DC voltage on the receiving end would decay faster than $1/r$, unlike the non-zero frequency components, and in the far field you may not measure a DC offset at all.

Comment: Ok thankyou. But I am using it for other purposes. Will the electric field at least detach and propagates?

Comment: yes, sure, except for the "dc" term it will "detach" and "propagate"  but you will have little or no control on the amount of radiation in any given direction. It is possible to make a multi frequency matching network that could, at least in principle,  match a few harmonics but even then the directional control will be very difficult to maintain.